# Will someone with many flagged comments get a comment ban?

Tags: support, feature-request, comments, comment-flags

IMO an offensive/chatty/opinionated comment is more destructive than an answer that is not 100% exact but tries to answer a question.

And more destructive than a legitimate question with relevance only to a few people.

And if there are no consequences of polluting the comments of a question then such a feature should be implemented.

Answer (score 18):

There is no automatic ban in place.  Moderators can manually ban a user that is sufficiently disruptive.

Comment: What if it's a moderator making chatty / off topic / offensive comments?

Comment: @DanBeale You can [contact an SE employee](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) to discuss issues with a moderator.

Comment: According to [these comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294672/does-comment-deletion-affect-my-privileges/294673?noredirect=1#comment506501_294673) the only way for moderators to ban users from commenting is to suspend them. I guess that's what you mean.