# Does comment deletion affect my privileges?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I am asking if increased number of deleted comments affect my privilege of writing comments? (I have deleted a huge number of comments in the past and I still can write comments either to my post or to others post).

Comment: @AndrewMyers It's related, but not really a duplicate. The other question asks if comment flags have any consequences, but this question mentions self-deleted comments. Also, the other question is a feature request and not this one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as "comment ban" - neither automated, nor manual.

The only way to stop a user from commenting is to suspend him/her.

Thousands of comments get deleted every day, most of them just noise.

If someone post losts of comments which are spam or offensive, moderator will usually just suspend/nuke the account anyway.

Comment: How about my suggestion of preventing users from deleting comments because it might change the context of the discussion (discussion to an answer or question)?

Comment: I'm against this idea, but you really better ask it as new question here, I answered the "main" question.

Comment: I have asked it in a seperate question [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294674/cant-deleted-comments-confuse-users-who-try-to-enter-into-a-discussion).

Comment: Cheers, but think it's better be tagged as [meta-tag:feature-request] since you actually ask to change the existing behavior of the system.

Comment: @MChaker Comments are not meant for prolonged discussion of the question; websites under the Stack Exchange umbrella are *not* forums.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286811/4284627), moderators can manually ban users from commenting.

Comment: @DonaldDuck no, I'm pretty sure he means full suspension, which among other things prevents the user from posting comments..

Comment: @DonaldDuck Servy's referring to completely suspending a user. There's no way to block a user from commenting specifically except suspending them from the site.

Comment: Only reviewing, chat and suggested edits (if below 2k rep) can be blocked separately by mods. The system automatically can do review bans, suggested edit bans, question bans, answer bans and flag bans. Everything else is covered by a full account suspension.