# What, if any, are the consequences for a user who has too many comments flagged "No Longer Needed"?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

I've read the following post but it only seems to discuss comment bans.

> [Flag commenting consequences?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286810/flag-commenting-consequences)

I've been asking OPs who have posted a question, commented underneath the question with additional code to instead edit their question with the relevant code. Once they have done this, I have flagged their comment as "No Longer Needed" as the code has been transferred to the question itself.

An example of this can be seen here: *(Question has now been deleted since, only >10k users can access the link)*

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933812/how-to-stop-firing-events-multiple-times-on-keydown-eventlistener#55933812

Will this have any negative effects against the OP that posted the comment in any way?

Comment: Related: [When is a comment hostile or unfriendly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373801/7795130), specifically the section in the question "Unfriendly and Rude flags Carry Consequences."

Comment: Note: Only moderators can see deleted comments, so your link to the question where your helpful flags have caused the comments to be deleted only shows a question with no comments.

Comment: You are doing exactly the right thing here. Keep it up.

Comment: It would be a good idea to let the user know that they can delete their own comments when they're no longer needed.

Comment: "No Longer Needed" comments cover cases where the comment either was never needed (which should carry some consequence) or started off being useful but then stopped being needed (which is exactly what we want to have happen to comments). This only focuses on dealing with the immediate problem of the comment not being needed instead of trying to get users to leave less unnecessary comments.

Comment: _Will this harm the OP that posted the comment in any way?_ please define `harm`

Comment: @Lewis in that case you might be misusing the term `harm`

Comment: [previous comments removed to reduce noise] - possibly, but not all harm has to be physical. I will update and clarify.

Comment: the word "detrimental" maybe more appropriate

Answer (score 101, accepted):

*"No longer needed"* flags carry no penalties, automatic or manual.

If comments are posted in good faith and removed as NLN afterwards then no moderator would impose a penalty of any kind for having these comments flagged and removed.

If edits to a post made comments obsolete, they can be safely flagged for removal without fear of consequences for anyone involved. Even inherently "noisy" comments like posting "thank-you" on each of your posts are removed harmlessly (It's theoretically possible to post harmless comments and yet abuse the system, e.g. flooding another user with inane comments that would otherwise be simply "meh", but in those cases, the issue would generally be resolved by a custom mod-flag, not by raising a "no-longer-needed" one).

Comment: Indeed. A comment that causes the post to be edited (making the comment itself obsolete in the process) is a good thing!

Comment: Although in this particular scenario it was the OP writing the comment so they should have just edited instead (or included the information to begin with)