# Is leaving many pointless comments a bannable offense?

Tags: support, flags, comments, account-suspension

I recently wrote a question about hiding for me personally all comments by a user who left many irritating useless comments under posts in a tag I'm active in.

I was looking for this because I assumed that actions of this user would not result in their ban: after all, comments are ephemeral, and could be rather quickly removed with "no longer needed" flags.

But today I've noticed one of their answers with reputation set to 1. I can see that they were banned. Assuming bans are usually for some round period, and their last activity, most likely they were banned for a month. Also, I see that all their comments are removed.

I understand that it is not allowed for moderators to discuss actions regarding other users, unless the user in question specifically allows this. But I would like to know in general if my assumption about bans for comments was wrong, and if there is a possibility to be banned for many raised "no longer needed" flags on your comment. Or might something like this happen only if somebody raises a custom flag, and a moderator finds a reason for ban (and what this reason might be)?

**TL;DR** If a user writes too many comments unrelated (or very loosely related) to matter of the question, can this user be banned?

Comment: I wouldn't put two and two together here ; why the user was suspended is very likely not going to be disclosed. That being said, *if* the user *was* providing a lot of noise on the site a moderator might have reached out to them to ask them to stop, or at least slow down. If the user didn't, then *that* could result in a suspension and they've explicitly ignored mod instructions. Alternatively, they could have done sometime else entirely.

Comment: And what can be a reason for removing all their comments?

Comment: I can't say for certain that the comments are the case, but I know that I've seen a couple of users I've flagged for severe misuse of comments get suspended after I've flagged their posts; but in both occasions I've had to raise around NLN 100 comment flags over the course of several months, as well as a couple of custom flags on posts.

Comment: *"And what can be a reason for removing all their comments?"* Misuse of the comments, presumably. My point in my first comment is that suspension reasons are *not* made public; reasons on the user's profile are given but it's often vague: Voting irregularities, to cool down, plagiarism. They aren't specific like "Abuse of the comment system after being asked to slow down."

Comment: In my opinion, if the mods believe the comments were posted on purpose to be useless, without any intention to be helpful, then yes, at some point they'll warn the user and then suspend if the user keep doing it. However, if the comments were posted "innocently" and served some purpose, and just left there without the user bothering to delete at some point, it's fine and can't/shouldn't lead to suspension. So most likely, the first option is what took place in your case.

Comment: When you have one problem, you usually have two problems. Similarly when you misbehave in one way, you tend to misbehave in other ways as well. That is essentially a good thing, it is hard for people to contain themselves so they will generally make themselves noticed at some point or another. All the more reason to not let it get to you. The bill comes due.

Comment: "*Also, I see that all their comments are removed.*" Just to make sure we're not missing the obvious... all their comments are gone presumably because you're using a userstyle to hide their comments, no?

Comment: @TylerH, of course no) I've checked with another browser.

Comment: Apparently I participated in a flame war once. Never figured out what I'd done, but with my rate of fire it's inevitable that I hit a suspendable offence sooner or later.

Answer (score 10):

In a strict sense, the guideline for commenting is stated on [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

> #### When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).
>
> #### When *shouldn't* I comment?
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - **Suggesting corrections** that don't *fundamentally* change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
> - **Answering a question** or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);
> - **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, upvote it and pay it forward;
> - **Criticisms** which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, downvote (and provide or upvote a better answer if appropriate);
> - **Secondary discussion** or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
> - **Discussion of community behavior or site policies**; please use meta instead.

So, if the user does obsessive commenting under "When *should't* I comment?", then they can be considered breaking the rules and thus warned and furthermore suspended, even if the content of the comments are benign.

> if there is a possibility to be banned for many raised "no longer needed" flags on your comment

As for "no longer needed", this depends on the context.

If the comments are originally helpful but then become outdated due to some reasons, then the comments have fulfilled their purposes and may get cleaned up without any penalty.

However, if the comments are used for other reasons, even for benign-but-chatty purposes, then these don't fulfill the purpose of the comments, and the user might get warned or suspended, depending on the severity.

Comment: By "this depends on the context" you meant that no automatic action happens or proposed if user has too many of the flags raised? And it fully depends on moderator, if they notice pattern of user leaving multiple undesired comments - they might take action, and if doesn't notice - nothing happens?

Comment: @markalex there is no auto-flag for too many "no longer needed" flags, only for ["harassment/unfriendly" flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203062/241919); there's also no comment-only ban. As for fully depends on the moderator, mods might notice more by putting a custom flag *on a post*, because flags on comments are automatically removed from the mod queue if deleted, and they're not grouped by the commenter, so if handled by different mods, they might not see the big picture.

Answer (score 7):

There is most likely no single answer to this question.  Suspension is one of many tools available to moderators.  My understanding is that when a situation arises that is harming the community, moderators make a judgement call about how to handle it.  In the case of a user leaving many comments that aren't suitable here, I expect the moderator might just delete the comments, or might warn the user, or might suspend them.  I doubt there is a hard-and-fast rule.  Also, there is often additional context that isn't visible to you but might influence the moderators' decisions.

I would suggest you contemplate why you are asking:

- If you are asking to understand what behavior of yours is allowed, then you already have the answer: it sounds like you do understand how comments should and shouldn't be used.
- If you want to know how to respond to situations where you observe another user leaving many unnecessary comments, it sounds like you already have the answer: flag the comments as obsolete, and if you perceive a pattern that is broad enough to be causing problems, you can leave a custom flag for moderator attention to explain the circumstances, and let the mods take it from there.
- If you are trying to speculate why another user was suspended, I would ask you to keep that to yourself and avoiding posting here or elsewhere about it.  I understand your curiousity but asking about that doesn't help anyone.  Suspensions are not intended as a form of public shaming.  We can't know the reasons why the user was acting in this way, and it's not our goal to try to shame them or brand them as problematic.  Instead, the goal is to protect the community, communicate our norms/expectations, and encourage them to change their behavior.

  You can't know all the context that went into the moderators' decision, and even if you did, how would it help you?  It wouldn't.  You don't need to know -- it is none of your business.  I encourage you to trust that moderators are taking actions that are reasonable given all of the available context; and to not pile onto a user who is suspended.  A suspension is a break to protect the community, and we hope that the user will learn from it, come back, and participate in the community in a helpful way.  I believe in personal growth and allowing others to grow and learn.  It does no one any good to have public speculation about past suspensions hanging around after the user returns from their suspension.  If you made a mistake and got suspended and learned from it, would you want a mark of shame hanging around on meta forever?  I wouldn't.  I encourage you to let these situations be handled in private, so that bygones can remain bygones.

---

See also [What, if any, are the consequences for a user who has too many comments flagged "No Longer Needed"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384439/781723), [Will someone with many flagged comments get a comment ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286810/781723).

Comment: I wanted to know if my initial assumption about non-worthiness (in terms of moderators time) of custom flag with something like "This users posts many useless unrelated to question comments" (but with details) was wrong. So basically your second point was a bit wrong.

Comment: And regarding shaming part, I do not intend to shame anybody, nor to expose them to shaming from anybody else. This is the reason, why no names or even tags were used. If my post was too revealing still, please explain me why, and I'll flag it myself with request to be removed.

Comment: @markalex, it would be better to just ask the simple and direct question: If I see a user who is repeatedly misusing comments, should I use a custom flag to bring that to moderators attention?  That's what you actually need to know (in contrast, you don't need to know whether they will/can be banned), and that is a question whose answer would be useful to others.  The answer to that question is yes, raising a custom flag for moderator attention is a reasonable approach.

Comment: You are right. I drifted away from main question I should be asking. Thanks for the help.